Flatpickr time_24hr
I've been trying for 2 days to set my hour format to 24 hours instead of AM/PM, but nothing works. I'm configuring it in Angular. Here is my TS part and my HTML part:
TypeScript:
flatpickrOptions: any = {
  locale: French,
  enableTime: true,
  noCalendar: true,
  time_24hr: true,
  dateFormat: 'H:i',
};

HTML:
<input
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  mwlFlatpickr
  [options]="flatpickrOptions"
/>

Thanks for helping

is time24hr
  flatpickrOptions: any = {
    enableTime: true,
    noCalendar: true,
    time24hr: true,
    dateFormat: 'H:i',
  };

See stackblitz
